# Satellites to retrieve UV bands

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, satellite

I want to retrieve some satellite images with UV bands, but I don't know which satellites are providing UV bands and whether we can freely download them.
I have already downloaded Modis and Landsat images, but about other satellites I have no idea where to start. I need some hints about satellites that have UV bands in their products. The spatial resolution is not important at this stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The US Naval Research Laboratory has developed the "Special Sensor Ultraviolet Spectrographic Imager" (SSUSI). Versions of it have been aboard DMSP satellites since 2003, improving in accuracy. It records in the extreme ultraviolet and far ultraviolet spectral ranges. The most recent numbers I could find (from 2011) said it has 7km resolution and records 80nm to 170nm wavelengths in 1.8nm spacing.

The data is freely available from their website, http://ssusi.jhuapl.edu/.

There's also the "Ozone Mapping and Profiler Suite" aboard NASA's Suomi NPP/JPSS satellite, which records in the 
250 to 380 nm range at somewhere between 10km and 50km resolution; you can get that data from NOAA CLASS. It's supposed to be the successor to the DMSP satellites.

Answer (score 5):

You won't have much luck finding a satellite that provides data from the ultra violet (UV) portion of the electromagnetic spectrum. The reason is that the wavelength of UV energy is so short that most of it gets absorbed or scattered by the atmosphere, or tiny particles in the atmosphere, before it even gets to the Earth (from the sun) let alone back up to any satellite.

See, for example,

- [www.udel.edu/Geography/DeLiberty/Geog474/geog474_energy_prin.html](http://www.udel.edu/Geography/DeLiberty/Geog474/geog474_energy_prin.html),
- [www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geomatics/satellite-imagery-air-photos/satellite-imagery-products/educational-resources/14635](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geomatics/satellite-imagery-air-photos/satellite-imagery-products/educational-resources/14635) or
- [hosting.soonet.ca/eliris/remotesensing/bl130lec3.html](http://hosting.soonet.ca/eliris/remotesensing/bl130lec3.html)

Even blue light, which has a longer wavelength than UV, from the sun gets so scattered by the atmosphere that when you look up (on a cloudless day) and away from the sun, the sky is not black, as it *should* be since there is no light source away from the sun, but it is blue – short-wavelength light (from the sun) that has been scattered all over the place.

There are some satellites that collect UV data (see the other answer) but they have a very low spatial resolution.

Comment: Thank for your information,Yes I know about absorption in this band,So you mean there is not any satellite which gatter data in this bands?or near this?I haven't seen your links yet because of bad Internet connection speed but I'll look at your provided links to find out more information,Thanks